# How to change progress of the circular seekbar in Android?

Tags: android, seekbar

How to change progress in the circular seek bar when I enter number in edittext and click on button?

Below is the snapshot of what I am trying to do

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer of my question.
If you want to show circular seekbar like mine in the above layout and want to send value which is coming from server use this code:

**https://github.com/RaghavSood/AndroidCircularSeekBar**

Change its layout according to your requirements in CircularSeekBar class

If you want to send value for its progress programatically. Then, **replace setProgress() with the below method:**

```
public void setProgress(int progress) //this is an Android function

    { 
        if (this.progress != progress) 
        { 
            this.progress = progress; 
            if (!CALLED_FROM_ANGLE) 
            { 
                int newPercent =this.progress; 
                int newAngle = (newPercent * 360)/100; 
                this.setAngle(newAngle); 
                this.setProgressPercent(newPercent); 
            } 
            mListener.onProgressChange(this, this.getProgress()); 
            CALLED_FROM_ANGLE = false; 
        } 
    }
```

Now, in activity where you are using this Circular Seek bar , set its progress using SetProgress() method . Like this:-

```
com.exp.CustomControls.CircularSeekBar dynamicSeekBar=(com.exp.CustomControls.CircularSeekBar)findViewById(R.id.img_score_rovr);
dynamicSeekBar.setMaxProgress(100);

dynamicSeekBar.setProgress(progress_score); // Here, you can send any value

dynamicSeekBar.invalidate();
```

All the best....

If you get any problem , let me know.......I have got expertise in it

Comment: I am using same Example for my app. But I have issue with that. I have CircularProgressBar in listview. So every ListIndex has the CircularSeekBar. Now when i go to another Screen and come back to that screen then that SeekBar view get changed and damaged.

Comment: try this....dynamicSeekBar.invalidate(); whereever u want to refresh the view.

Comment: I'm also using this in a Fragment which is displayed via an Activity. The Activity displays another fragment first, then I switch (replace the first one) with the fragment that has the CircularSeekBar. It appears on screen but it is not displaying correctly. It appears to need a refresh / reload. It works fine if I display its fragment first, via the activity. The problem only occurs when it is display second. I've tried the invalidate but no luck. Where should I use the invalidate I've tried in the public void onResume() & public void onStart() of the fragment is this the correct location?

Comment: Am trying to use the seekbar to set different progresses using a for loop and then place markers on each to the progresses....any suggestions

Answer (score 2):

http://devadvance.com/circularseekbar/

I developed a completely new CircularSeekBar for another app, and decided to make it open source. The one by RaghavSood functions decently, but is not customizable and does not have setProgress/getProgress methods that work correctly.

Let me know if this helpful at all.

Edit: Callback when using a TextView on your layout:

```
public class CircleSeekBarListener implements OnCircularSeekBarChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(CircularSeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        // Put your code here
        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1);

        text.setText("" + progress);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can the actual "current number" be displayed in the middle of the circle?

Comment: The CircularSeekBar does not have a TextView built into it. Instead, you can simply add a TextView to your layout in the middle of the circle (or anywhere else), and add a callback to your code (see above).

Answer (score 0):

to change the progress of `ProgressBar` you have to call `setProgress(int)` on your `ProgressBar` instance

Comment: It's customized circular seekbar.....its code is below:

Comment: @BhawnaBhalla if it is a ProgressBar the correct way to change its progress is to use setProgress.

Comment: No its a class which is extending View class, and accordlingly I have drawn this circular seekbar using canvas

Comment: and why you can not extend ProgressBar instead of View? Since ProgressBar extends already view

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple piece of code to create circular progress bar.

```
private void circularImageBar(ImageView iv2, int i) {

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 300,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b); 
    Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#c4c4c4"));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawCircle(150, 150, 140, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFDB4C"));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);   
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        final RectF oval = new RectF();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        oval.set(10,10,290,290);
        canvas.drawArc(oval, 270, ((i*360)/100), false, paint);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);    
        paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#8E8E93")); 
        paint.setTextSize(140);
        canvas.drawText(""+i, 150, 150+(paint.getTextSize()/3), paint); 
        iv2.setImageBitmap(b);
}
```